# Is it possible to detect repaint/reflow in the browser?

Tags: javascript

Not sure if there is a solution to this problem. I want to know if there is a way to detect when the browser **actually** updates the UI.

Lets say I want add a class to an element just before I run a long-running, synchronous block of code, after the synchronous function runs, the class would be removed.

```
el.classList.add('waiting');
longRunningSynchronousTask();
el.classList.remove('waiting');
```

If I run this code, the long running task will get started, and block the UI before the class is added. I tried using `MutationObserver`'s, and checking the element with `getComputedStyle`, but that doesn't work because those don't reflect when the realtime updates the UI.

Using a worker might be the best solution (drop the long running code in a worker and post a message when it's complete to remove the class). This isn't really an option me, due to needing to support older browsers.

The only solution that works outside of implementing a worker is using `setTimeout`. I'd love to know if anyone has run into this problem and if there is any way to detect a repaint/reflow of the UI in the browser.

See my example for a better illustration of the problem.

```js
const el = document.querySelector('.target');
const isRed = c => c === 'red' || 'rgb(255, 0, 0)';

let classActuallyApplied = false;

let requestId;

const longRunningTask = (mil, onComplete) => {
  if (classActuallyApplied) {
    cancelAnimationFrame(requestId);
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date().getTime() < start + mil);
    onComplete();
  } else {
     requestId = requestAnimationFrame(longRunningTask.bind(null, mil, onComplete));
  }
}

const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
 classActuallyApplied = mutations
   .filter(mutation => {
   return mutation.type === 'attributes' &&
       mutation.attributeName === 'class' &&
        mutation.target.classList.contains('waiting');
  }).length > 0;
});

const observerConfig = {
 attributes: true, 
 childList: false, 
 characterData: false 
};

observer.observe(el, observerConfig);

el.addEventListener('click', e => {
 el.classList.add('waiting');
  longRunningTask(1000 * 5, () => {
   // el.classList.remove('waiting');
  });
});
```

```css
.target {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.waiting {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="target">
  target
</div>
```

Comment: You want to detect it or to trigger it ? I don't get what's the point of detecting would be in your case

Comment: If you know the conditions that cause the UI to be updated in your code, then just add appropriate callouts there. If it is based on window resize, then just add the appropriate listeners.

Comment: @DenysSéguret I want to detect when the UI is updated. If I add the `waiting` class, for example, it will change the text color to red. I want to know when the UI has been updated for the user. Once it is updated, I can start my long running task.

Comment: Isn't using setTimeout with 0 as its ms argument good enough? Put your long sync task inside a setTimeout with 0 ms as the time argument, and your function as the first argument.

Comment: @elad.chen Yeah. That's probably good enough. That was my initial solution. But I'm curious, why I find  I'm unable to detect when the UI has been updated.

Comment: Step back a bit and look at the problem differently: what is causing the UI to be updated? For example your code, user interaction or something else. Which updates do you care about?

Answer (score 4):

I believe [requestIdleCallback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestIdleCallback) is what you are looking for.

From [developers.google.com 2016](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/08/using-requestidlecallback?hl=en):

> In the same way that adopting requestAnimationFrame allowed us to schedule animations properly and maximize our chances of hitting 60fps, requestIdleCallback will schedule work when there is free time at the end of a frame, or when the user is inactive.

It is an experimental feature but (as of March 2021) is supported in most modern browsers. See [MDN Compatibility Table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestIdleCallback#browser_compatibility) and [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/requestidlecallback).